# IntelliSense is not woking SQL Server 2017

Tags: ssms, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I am using SQL Server 2017 and I had already installed Visual Studio 2019 before installing SQL Server. Sometimes when I create the first table in a database it gives me IntelliSense for that first table only and not for other tables I create later on and seomtimes it does not detect my tables and underline with a red line in my query.

I have tried the solution provided here ([IntelliSense not working but it is enabled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/intellisense-not-working-but-it-is-enabled)) with settings and clearing cache but it didn't work for me. The link was provided for a Microsoft solution which I did not try because it is for SQL Server 2008 .
please give me a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliSense not working but it is enabled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/intellisense-not-working-but-it-is-enabled)

Comment: No it does not helped me out

Comment: Try: [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)