# SSMS IntelliSense not working with sa user

Tags: ssms, intellisense

In SSMS (versions 17 and 18), IntelliSense is not working with the sa user, but it is working with another user.

If I connect to a SQL database with the sa user and create a query window, IntelliSense does not work in this window.
However, if I make a second connection to the same database with another user and create a query window, IntelliSense works.
If change back to the query window with sa user, IntelliSense again does not work.
[image: IntelliSense AutoComplete]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliSense not working but it is enabled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/intellisense-not-working-but-it-is-enabled)

Comment: A Linked Server and a Synonym have been declared, which was included in a view and the connection to LinkedServer has been lost.
LinkedServer and Synonym were deleted and re-created.
Question closed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user in sql, it is generally assigned the default bd you want to work with, that's why the IntelliSense works for you, although I think you shouldn't use the SA user for that, you can make the IntelliSense work by calling the bd with which you want to make inquiries ...

```
use [yourdb]
select * from yourtable
```

[image: example]

Comment: For sa user, intellisense worked fine until last week. sa is a db owner. The other user for whom intellisense works has limited rights.